# Lambda suppresses CA1062

Tags: c#, lambda, code-analysis, fxcop

I noticed that the simple act of using the argument of a public method in the body of a lambda would erroneously suppress warnings about CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods.  The following code does not produce a violation warning in VS2013.

```
public void BusinessLogic(MyType maybeNull)
{
    Func<object> validated = () => maybeNull;
    maybeNull.DoSomething();
}
```

This concerns me mainly not because you might get a false negative every once in a while, but because I'm specifically working on an expression-based validation helper method for one-line guard clauses that check the passed in expression for null and then uses some reflection trickery to output the ArgumentNullException with the correct parameter name.  It looks something along the lines of `ValidateNotNull(()=>maybeNull);`.  The fact that the lambda hides the violation means I can't tell if I am implementing it in such a way that FxCop understands.

I'm guessing something about the wrapping of the argument into the class which the compiler generates for the closure must be interfering.

Is there a good reason that FxCop should be ignoring this, or is it just a bug as I currently consider it?